# Java factorial output

Tags: java, output, factorial

I am supposed to create a program that asks the user for a number and takes the factorial of that number then asks if they want to do another factorial (Y,N).

It is supposed to work like this:

- Enter a number to take the factorial of: 4
- 4! = 24
- Do another factorial (Y,N)? Y
- Repeat until N is entered

My output is like:

- Enter a number to take the factorial of:
- "Do another factorial? (Y,N)?"
- 4! = 1 regardless of whether I enter Y or N.

  Here's my code:

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class factorial
  {
       public static void main ( String [] args )
       {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter a number you want to take the factorial of: ");
       int num = input.nextInt();
       int fact = 1;
       System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n ", num, fact, Factorial(num, fact));
   } 
       public static int Factorial(int num, int fact)
       {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           char foo;

            System.out.print("Do another factorial (Y,N)?");
            foo = input.next().charAt(0);

               for (int i = 1; i >= num; i++)
               {   
                   fact *= i;
                   if (foo == 'Y')
                   {
                       System.out.print("Do another factorial (Y,N)?");
                       foo = input.next().charAt(0);
                       continue;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       break;
                   }
               }
               return fact;  

       }

  }
  ```

After the change:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class factorial
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number you want to take the factorial of: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        int fact = 1;

        System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n ", num, Factorial(num, fact));

        System.out.print("Do another factorial (Y,N)? ");
        char  foo = input.next().charAt(0);

        while (foo != 'N')
        {
            System.out.print("Do another factorial (Y,N)? ");
            foo = input.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Enter a number you want to take the factorial of: ");
        num = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n", num, Factorial(num, fact));
    }
}
    public static int Factorial(int num, int fact)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {   
                fact *= i;
            }
            return fact; 
    }
```

}

Output still has some problems:

- Enter a number to take the factorial of: 4
- 4! = 24
- Do another factorial (Y,N)? Y
- Do another factorial (Y,N)? Y
- Enter a number to take the factorial of: 4
- 4! = 24
- Do another factorial (Y,N)? N
- Enter a number to take the factorial of:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compute factorial, but you never print it:

```
System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n ", num, fact, Factorial(num, fact));
```

should be

```
System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n ", num, Factorial(num, fact));
```

Moreover, your `Factorial` function does not make use of the `fact` parameter, so you should remove it, and declare a local variable inside the function.

Finally, asking for the "do you want another factorial" should be done at the top level, not inside the `Factorial` function. Your code does not use the character that the user inputs, too: you'll need a loop that checks user's input, and continues while `Y` is entered.

Comment: How exactly would I implement a loop that checks whether the user entered Y or N then asks the user for another number? I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to java.

Comment: Figured out how to check if the user entered Y or N but now I am stuck on how to do the factorial calculation again after the user enters Y

Comment: @user1858350 You may want to edit your question, and post your new code in a separate "after the change" block.

Comment: @user1858350 You're almost there: replace `while (foo != 'N')` with `while (true)`, do the check inside the loop, after the user enters `foo`, and add `if (foo == 'N') break;` to exit the loop in the middle.

Comment: After the first iteration, it asks "Do another factorial?" twice if I enter Y, then will repeat and if I enter N it will ask me to enter a number, do the calculation and exit. Maybe I put the if statement in the wrong place?

Comment: @user1858350 You need the `if (foo == 'N')` check right after the `foo = input.next().charAt(0);` line.

Comment: It still asks me "Do another factorial?" twice after the first run, but otherwise it seems all other problems are fixed.

Comment: @user1858350 There are two printouts for `"Do another factorial..."` - one before and one inside the loop. You need to keep only the one inside the loop. You also need to move the printout to after the first calculation has been completed, so that the first run asked only for the number and not for `Y/N`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error:

```
System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n ", num, fact, Factorial(num, fact))
```

Your output is not really `Factorial(num, fact)` but `fact`, this should be:

```
System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n ", num, Factorial(num, fact))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below lines of code:

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Do another factorial (Y,N)?");

from Factorial method.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code as follows:

- There should be a method that takes an `int` and returns its factorial, and does nothing else.
- All the input/output, as well as the "Do another factorial?" loop, should be done in `main()`.

This will make it easier to get the logic right.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
public static void main ( String [] args )
     {
     String yesno ="Y";
     while(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
     {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter a number you want to take the factorial of: ");
         int num = input.nextInt();
         System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n ",num,fact(num));
         System.out.print("Do another factorial (Y,N)?");
         Scanner inputKey = new Scanner(System.in);
         yesno = inputKey.nextLine();

     }
     }
```

Here is factorial function:

```
public static int fact(int num)
    {
        if(num<=1)
        {
            return 1;

        }else{
            return (num*(fact(num-1))); 
        }
    }
```